# how to make cURL call in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlrequest

Please any one help to make cURL call of below url

curl -u "demo:demo" -H "Accept: application/json" http://api.holdsport.dk/v1/teams

it would really helpful for me to continue my project. demo:demo is username and password

Thanks.

Comment: Look into `NSTask`, better yet look into `NSURLConnection` or `AFNetworking`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) project which cURL is based on is C based and will run perfectly fine as C is an Objective-C subset (many examples [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html)). Although if you are targeting Cocoa/Cocoa Touch only, then the NSURLConnection classes (or higher-level ASIHTTPRequest or AFNetworking third party libraries) would be very much easier (with asynchronous handling out of the box).

EDIT: Actually if you really want to use cURL, there are [Cocoa bindings for it](http://code.google.com/p/curlhandle/).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've seen http requests made

```
//Create a new url request with our url path
myRequest_ = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_PATH]];
myRequest_.delegate = self;

//send out the request as asynchronous
[myRequest_ startAsynchronous];
```

http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/10/16/iphone-dev-how-to-communicate-with-server-using-http-json-and-phpor-any-server-side-language/

Comment: It should be noted that `ASIHTTPRequest` is awesome, but non standard.  It's a library that you integrate into you app.

Comment: I would recommend people to learn how to use standard libraries before using non standard extensions. In many cases people use ASIHTTPRequest only because they didn't now there is a standard library with the same funcionality.